# generate Model after creating views and controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Im new to coding and started Rails. I've created a controller Pages and each time I wanted to add a site page I'd create its view (in pages), route and controller def. I did not create a model named Pages.

I'm trying to activate the Search button among other things and see they refer back to the Model (which I did not create). Can I **rails g Model pages** now? Or should I have done this before creating the pages.

Comment: can you provide more information on Search button? Generally you don't need a model if the only thing you do is rendering views from controllers without any data from models.

Comment: The Seach button should look into my content site (with multiple pages) and look which page has the word that was typed into the Search button. From what I have been searching is that I need to index the pages, add tags and if I want to do SEO I've seen over and over the Model is essential. So I think I absolutely need the Model I'm just not sure if I can add it 'now'?

Comment: I am not into design of your solution, while if I had a set of views where I have to make search I would create a model `PagesAnalytic` which would implement `#search_for_word` method`. This method could open each view file and parse it according to your needs. More specific need could end up in better answer.

Comment: This does sound like a better solution for the Search button thanks so much! But I think a Model pages will be need for tags and for chaning the URL path (which is changed in the Model to_param from what I've researched). So if I do need the Model could I create it now or will it impact my whole project somehow? Its so silly because I forgot the M in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can serve your static pages with [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage). That is one very good example of Pages model implementation. Even if it is not exactly what you are looking for it is good source for inspiration.